# Expression has changed after it was checked for async?

Tags: angular

I have tried some answers from stackoverflow, but no result:

**Template is:**

```
<div class="overlay" *ngIf="isLoading() | async">
```

**Code:**

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoaderService {
    public countRequests = 0;
    private loading = new BehaviorSubject(false);

    get isLoading(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.loading.asObservable();
    }

    start(): void {
        this.countRequests++;
        this.loading.next(true);
    }

    stop(): void {
        this.loading.next(false);
    }
}


   isLoading(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.loaderService.isLoading;
    }
```

**Error:**

> LoaderComponent.html:1 ERROR Error:
> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
> after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value:
> 'ngIf: true'.

I have tries to solve it passed default value:

```
private loading = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

Comment: Try adding a 'delay', with `setTimeOut` or `delay` of `rxjs/operators`

Comment: In the development mode, Angular runs 2 changedetection cycles. If the value of the binding changes between these 2 cycles, that is when you get the error. This will not happen in the prod mode, but is most likely due to some error in the logic. In your case, it depends on when the start method is called. If the start method is called as a result of the first changedetection cycle, then it will throw this error since when the second cycle runs, it finds the value has changed.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I change `this.loading` some times for each request/response so it is blinking. How to improve it?

Comment: Have you write anytihng about `isLoading()` in `constructor` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the method in html template. Try to create one observable in your component and assign the value in ngAfterViewInit() method and use that variable in your html template

Template:

```
<div class="overlay" *ngIf="isLoading | async">
```

Code:

```
isLoading = new BehaviorSubject(false);

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.isLoading = this.loaderService.isLoading();
}
```